# How to extract python dictionary information

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

## I have the following code:

```
def car(userid):
    return "Car: %s!" % car_models.get(userid, 'This car model does not exist in the database.')


car_models = {
    382: "Onix - Model 2018",
    950: "HB20 - Model 2018",
    590: "Citroen - Model 2016",
}
```

## I can extract information through:

```
>>> car(382)
'Car: Onix - Model 2018!'
```

## However, I would like to extract information this way:

```
cars = {'Chevrolet':{'Onix':'Model 2018',
                     'Selta':'Model 2017'},
        'Ford':{'Fusion':'Model 2009',
                      'Ranger':'Model 2015'}}
```

## I would like to extract the information this way:

```
>> car(Onix)
'Car: Onix - Model 2018!'
```

I confess that I have tried many things and I can not hit

Comment: Could you clarify better the last two bolded points?  They appear to be asking to do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary with keys which are strings are a stored as a hash list. So your dictionary has Onix stored in the address under Chevrolet. So we can access it as

```
cars['Chevrolet']
```

> {'Onix': 'Model 2018', 'Selta': 'Model 2017'}

```
cars['Chevrolet']['Onix']
```

> 'Model 2018'

---

If you do not know what brand makes a specific model. Youc an find it using a list comprehension as

```
cars = {'Chevrolet':{'Onix':'Model 2018',
                     'Selta':'Model 2017'},
        'Ford':{'Fusion':'Model 2009',
                      'Ranger':'Model 2015'}}

model = 'Selta'
brand = [car for car in cars for m in cars[car] if m == model][0]

print('Car: ' + model + ' - ' + cars[brand][model])
```

You can just change the `model` variable and it will find out under what brand the model can be found.

---

You can then make a small utility function

```
def getInfo(cars, model):
    brand = [car for car in cars for m in cars[car] if m == model][0]
    return 'Car: ' + model + ' - ' + cars[brand][model]

cars = {'Chevrolet':{'Onix':'Model 2018',
                     'Selta':'Model 2017'},
        'Ford':{'Fusion':'Model 2009',
                      'Ranger':'Model 2015'}}

print(getInfo(cars, 'Ranger'))
```

Comment: **It certainly helped me. Thanks for the attention and help.**